# Is it possible to reload all the rows in a section without reloading the header of that section?

Tags: uitableview

I need to selectively reload a `UITableView`. I've tried the following methods but they don't suit my needs as I need a full reload of all section rows but not a reload of the section header. (The rest of the table should stay in place except for the sections rows)

option 1: not good because it also reloads the section header . I don't want the section header to reload because it contains editable text from the user

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:MySection] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

option 2 :

```
// not good because the number of rows doesn't stay the same in between reloads - this is the reason i need to reload!
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

option 3:

```
// not good because I don't get the animation with the previous 2 options
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Slightly unsure why you can't use reloadRows? If the number of rows has changed in the section, why aren't you inserting them, and then reloading each cell?

Comment: Lets say you have 10 rows in the section , and then you want to have 5 rows in the section , I'm not clear how you would reload rows 1...5 and then delete rows 6-10

Comment: It could be a few steps , deleting , inserting, reloading etc. The simplist would be something in the lines of: self.tableView reloadSectionRows:MySection];

Comment: Can you use, [self.tableView beginUpdates] // perform your deletions/insertions/reloads [self.tableView endUpdates]; ?

Comment: I think the trick is to always reload all index paths in that section , after inserting or deleting the amount of rows that have changed . I was having a problem thought that the data source was called twice because of the initial insert/delete and then reload rows action